# Get files and operate on their file size

Tags: c, string

I've an algorithm as

**1.** Scan all files in a directory (done using C)

**2.** Get the file size of the current file in the loop (done using C)

**3.** If it is less than 8 kb do something and store the next immediate file name in an array (Seems like there is no support for associative array in C)

I've done this in PHP but due to unforeseeable events, it now needs to be written in C. I did go through quite a few tutorials on C and honestly speaking I underestimated the time I thought I would require to get the basics right.

After quite a considerable time, I managed to get my hands on a code that lists out the files in a directory.

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{ 
  char path = "D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\frames\\"; 
  DIR           *d;
  struct dirent *dir;
  char test;
  d = opendir("D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\frames\\");
  if (d)
  {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
    {      
       printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
    }

    closedir(d);
  }
  getchar();
  return(0);
}
```

Now it's obvious that the current file in a loop is represented by `dir->d_name`. The thing where I'm stuck is to take this and append it to `"D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\frames\\"` so that the path becomes `"D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\frames\\somename.jpg"`

This will help me to get the direct path of a file. Once I get that I will have the required data to move to step 2. The problem I'm facing right now is string concatenation. I tried `strcat()` but that didn't work out.

So basically what I'm looking for is

```
while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
{      
   // merge "path" and "dir->d_name" to get something similar like
   // "D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\frames\\somename.jpg"
}
```

Any help, suggestions?

Comment: Why mention PHP at all? You don't show the PHP code you're trying to convert, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: Just in case a PHP guy who did something similar might come across this..and someone did remove the tag.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended solution in plain C is `snprintf`:

```
char buf[MAX_PATH];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%s%s", path, dir->d_name);
```

Don't use `strcat()` or `strncat()`.

If you are using MSVC, then your C implementation is 24 years out of date, and `snprintf()` is not available.  Your options are:

1. Use `_snprintf()` and then `buf[sizeof(buf)-1] = '\0';` as a workaround.
2. Use C++ and `std::string`.
3. Use Cygwin.

Comment: Using a fixed size buffer is problematic. This is why in my answer I suggested asprintf(), though I'm not certain MSVC supports it. Of course, the OP never mentions compiler.

Comment: This did work. Also, I have no idea what compiler I'm using. Though I know I'm using Dev C++ environment

Comment: @mah: Pathnames on Windows have a maximum length.  Fixed size buffers are therefore no problem in this particular case, since you can just make the buffer `MAX_PATH` long.

Comment: +1 for a working solution. I shall try to move to step 2 and see what I come up against.

Comment: There is, of course, a way to make longer paths if you prefix them with \\?\, but then you have to use `wchar_t` instead of `char`.

Comment: I did manage to figure out the Step 2 too. Moving on to step 3

Answer (score 1):

`strcat()` is only valid if your string has enough space to hold the result, and it will make the destination invalid for subsequent passes through your loop.

I would suggest instead the `asprintf()` function though it has a small caveat; it will allocate memory which you are responsible for returning.

```
while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
{
   char *fullname;
   asprintf(&fullname, "%s%s", "D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\frames\\", dir->d_name);
   printf("%s\n", fullname);

   // now do things with `fullname`

   free(fullname); // return the memory allocation at the end of the loop
}
```

Comment: That threw up an error probably because I'm using wrong headers or didn't include them.

Comment: @asprin: Those headers probably don't exist on your system.  `asprintf()` is non-standard; it appears on Glibc and Linux and some others though.

Comment: Ah..makes sense...I'm on Windows 7